# jQuery - Getting the closest div from unknown HTML

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the closest div from another element. My use case:

I use a spinner as placeholder while AJAXing. The spinner is only affected to the parent div which means I can have multiple spinners on one page.

I figured I could reuse a function for this but I can never get the spinner div.

My example:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h4></h4>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <div id='wrapper'>
        <div class='ajax_spinner'></div>
        <div>
            <h4></h4>
            <div>
                <button>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>
            </h4>
            <div>
                <button id='1659'>
                    3XL
                </button>
                <button id='1662'>
                    4XL
                </button>
                <button id='1650'>
                    L
                </button>
                <button id='1647'>
                    M
                </button>
                <button id='1644'>
                    S
                </button>
                <button id='1653'>
                    XL
                </button>
                <button id='1641'>
                    XS
                </button>
                <button id='1656'>
                    XXL
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id='add_to_cart'>
            Add to Cart
            <div class='ajax_spinner'></div>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the example above I have a spinner that should affect quite a large area (the wrapper div) when clicking a size button. But also have a spinner for only the add to cart button. So I can never know exactly where I have the ajax_spinner.

I tried a `findSpinner` function:

```
const findSpinner = (el) => {
    let spinner = el.closest('#ajax_spinner')
    spinner.length ? spinner : el.siblings('#ajax_spinner')
    spinner.length ? spinner : el.parentsUntil('#ajax_spinner')
    spinner.length ? spinner : el.parent('#ajax_spinner')
    spinner.length ? spinner : el.parents('#ajax_spinner')
    spinner.length ? spinner : el.find('#ajax_spinner')
    return spinner.length ? spinner : null
}
```

`el` in this case is the clicked jquery element. If I do `let spinner = el.parent().parent().siblings('#ajax_spinner')` it obviously finds spinner for size picking. But I cannot use this because it is not always the case.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use this below?

```
document.getElementById('ajax_spinner');
```

getElementById() returns an Element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string. Since element IDs are required to be **unique** if specified, they're a useful way to get access to a specific element quickly.
AS i see id is uniq so you can select it directly with js or you can selct it with jQuery like below

```
$('#ajax_spinner')
```

**EDIT**
Sorry if i missed something but in your html there is no uniq id you wrote them like class =

> class='ajax_spinner'

If you want to do it with classes. i wrote some code for you that loop from child to parent to top of the html. In this way it finds the closest **ajax_spinner** DOM i hope its right

When function found any dom it will change his bgcolor and log the tagname.

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p></p>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p></p>
            </div>

            <div>
                <h4></h4>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>

            <div id='wrapper'>
                <div class='ajax_spinner'></div>
                <div>
                    <h4></h4>
                    <div>
                        <button>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>
                    </h4>
                    <div>
                        <button id='1659'>
                            3XL
                        </button>
                        <button id='1662'>
                            4XL
                        </button>
                        <button id='1650'>
                            L
                        </button>
                        <button id='1647'>
                            M
                        </button>
                        <button id='1644'>
                            S
                        </button>
                        <button id='1653'>
                            XL
                        </button>
                        <button id='1641'>
                            XS
                        </button>
                        <button id='1656'>
                            XXL
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id='add_to_cart'>
                    Add to Cart
                    <div class='ajax_spinner'></div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const findSpinner = (el) => {
            let found = null;
            while (found == null) {
                if (el.find('.ajax_spinner').length > 0) return el.find('.ajax_spinner')
                if (el.closest('.ajax_spinner').length > 0) return el.closest('.ajax_spinner')
                el = el.parent()
            }
            return found;
        }
        $('button').on('click', function (event) {
            const found = findSpinner($(this))
            if (found) {
                found.css('background', 'red')
                console.log(found.prop("tagName"));
            }
        })
    </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: Sure, I agree with ID should be unique. However this does not answer my question at all. You answered with something different than what I am asking for. My question was how to get a closest div from an element without knowing the HTML. The case could be with classes or data attributes too. My question was not "How do I get #ajax_spinner".

I have modified my question to be classes instead of ID's

Comment: i have edited and made some new function for you. And think i miss understood because you use # with class name. thats why i thought you use id as uniq :)